# By replacing capacitor values with different ones in a circuit, will the circuit still work?

Tags: capacitor, high-pass-filter

[image]

I'm fairly new to electronics and following this schematic for a "Truth Meter", which detects sweat from your fingertips and a lights up an LED depending on the resistance of the skin, as one of my first projects. Anyway, I do not have the 10nF capacitor that I am supposed to use but I do have 22 pF, 10 uF, 0.1 uF, and 100 uF capacitors. What combination, if any, of the capacitors that I have, will make this circuit work. Also, does it matter if I use 1n4007 diodes vs the 1n4001 diodes I am supposed to use? Thanks.

Comment: I can’t tell what wires make connections and what don’t. You should use zero ambiguity when drawing a circuit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That circuit is crap.  Run away.  Just from the look of the schematic, it's obvious that whoever designed this didn't know what they were doing.  Some problems:

There are no junction dots anywhwere.  That's the standard, for good reason.  Not only is it aggrevating to look at by those that are used to seeing proper schematics, but it also results in ambiguity.  Is the node between R3 and D1 connected to the vertical line between C2 and IC1A or is it not?

LED1 is shown with current going up.

There is no connection to the cathode of LED1 at all!

The opamp power connections aren't shown (this is giving the designer the benefit of the doubt to assume he knows power is supposed to be connected).

What are the V+ and V- voltage levels?

What is "V"?  It only appears at left connected to R4.

Then there's the circuit itself:

This circuit does not "Measure skin R" as the comment states.  It measures the *change* in skin resistance over a narrow frequency range, roughly ½ Hz to 5 Hz.  If the subject's skin resistance changes more slowly than that, or if it starts out sweaty, then this circuit won't detect it.

Noise on V+ and V will end up in the signal.  Perhaps they are simply hoping that noise won't be in the detectable frequency range.  A little filtering would be a good idea.

Like I said, run away.

However, to answer you specific questions:

> I do not have the 10nF capacitor that I am supposed to use but I do have 22 pF, 10 uF, 0.1 uF, and 100 uF capacitors.

So get some.  10 nF capacitors are readily and cheaply available from the other end of the internet.  Get a range of values if you plan to be tinkering with electronics.

You seem to be asking about C1.  That and C3 need to be close to the values shown for this circuit to work as intended.  C1 together with R8 set the low pass filter rolloff frequency.  Likewise, C3 together with R5 set the high pass filter rolloff frequency.  There are ways to use different capacitor values, but then you'd have to change resistors.  That changes the impedences and the gain, which also has to be considered.  In short, leave R5 and R8 alone, and use close to the capacitor values specified.

> Also, does it matter if I use 1n4007 diodes vs the 1n4001

No, not in this case.  D1, D2, and D3 are used only to make a voltage a little above V1.  Just about any silicon diodes would work in that role.  1N4001 are probably what the author had in his junk box, LOL.  In a real design, these would be small signal diodes, like 1N4148.

Comment: yeah, I should probably just do another project lol, thanks

Answer (score 2):

1) **Don't expect too much from this circuit**, since it has an AC coupled input it will respond only to quick changes to the resistance between inputs. "Lie detection" is not that easy. This is a **gimmick**, just be aware of that.

And I agree with Andy's comment: this circuit is drawn by a nincompoop, i.e. someone who doesn't have clue. For example: it is unclear where the cathode of the LED should connect, it's drawn "up" and that would suggest Vcc but then the LED is never going to light up.

You might just want to consider to do yourself a favor and **forget and ignore this circuit**. Almost any other electronics project would be a better way to spend your time.

2) you could try the 0.1 uF (= 100 nF) capacitor instead of the 10 nF. If that doesn't work, don't blame the 100 nF capacitor. Like I said in 1), this is a simple circuit. You cannot expect much from it.

3) 1N4007 and 1N4001 are basically the same diode except that the 1N4007 can withstand much higher reverse voltages. 1N4001 can handle 50 V while the 1N4007 can handle 1000 V. Since this circuit operated on much less than 50 V, both diodes are OK to use.

4) **Probably the most important tip:** If you're going to connect this circuit to an actual person, **use a battery to power the circuit**. I would not suggest using any other form of power source as there is the risk of "a tingle" (small shock) or a severe one (big shock) if the supply is faulty. So be safe, use a battery. Yes hospitals use mains powered devices that do connect directly to patients. But that equipment has to pass **very extensive** safety tests and requirements.